# How to pause a while loop until a certain key is pressed?

Tags: python, winapi, while-loop, pyautogui, win32con

I want the clicking to pause when you press `xbutton1` and it to continue when I press `xbutton2`.

Here's my code:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import pyautogui

click = True


def clicking():
    get = win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_LBUTTON)
    if get < 1:
        pyautogui.click()


def stop():
    if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_XBUTTON1):
        click = False


def continue_program():
    if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_XBUTTON2):
        click = True


while True:
    if click == True:
        clicking()

    else:
        stop()
```

Comment: You can check the 2 buttons clicked status at the begin of the while loop to confirm pause or continue, if the resutl is pause ,your while loop should use ```continue``` to pass through the loop code.

Comment: @ElapsedSoul I'm new to coding so I don't exactly understand this in words so if you could please change my code to how it's supposed to work that would be great. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

```py
import win32api
import win32con
import pyautogui

click = True


def clicking():
    get = win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_LBUTTON)
    if get < 1:
        pyautogui.click()


def check():
    if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_XBUTTON1):
        click = False
    if win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_XBUTTON2):
        click = True
    # Actually, here still has some contitions to check.
    return click


while True:
    if not check():
        continue
    # The things you want the loop to do. 
    clicking()
```

Comment: [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate): ""The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue."* The presented code doesn't read messages from its message queue. Consequently, it cannot observe synchronous key state.

Comment: @llnspectable I don't know much about these apis. I just tell the logic.Thought is more important than skill. Your comment is another problem, which I already mentioned in my code with ```# Actually, here still has some contitions to check.``` . As we know keyborad i/o event must be asynchronous while his code is synchronous .

Comment: Switching from synchronous input handling to asynchronous input handling exchanges a robust solution for one that occasionally/frequently fails. Robust input handling on Windows means switching to an event-based paradigm. That's a difficult departure for many Python developers that are too used to writing code that's strictly linear.

Comment: @IInspectable The poster ask for his doubt about pausing the loop. I just give the answer about this, because I'm not familiar with these apis. Maybe you could give him a solution for the error you mentioned.